# Which algorithm does "encrypt home directory" use?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

When encrypting a user's home directory, either during the install procedure or later using ecryptfs-migrate-home, what encryption algorithm / key size is used by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above answer is right, that AES is the cipher, but the reasoning is wrong.

User's home directories are configured by the script [ecryptfs-setup-private](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-setup-private).

In that shell script, the cipher and key length are harcoded:

```
CIPHER="aes" 
KEYBYTES="16"
```

Likewise, in the C source code of the setuid mount helper, [mount.ecryptfs_private](http://manpg.es/mount.ecryptfs_private), it is also hardcoded:

```
#define KEY_BYTES 16    
#define KEY_CIPHER "aes"
```

These values were hard coded to minimize the support burden of helping millions of users encrypt their home directories.

Answer (score 9):

The default `ecryptfs` algorithm is ***aes***.

It can be shown during the creation of a new encrypted mount point of folder that only ***aes*** is presently loaded but `ecryptfs` supports other logarithms.

```
bruno@ubuvbox:~$ sudo mount -t ecryptfs secret/ ~/secret/
Passphrase: 
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (loaded)
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56 (not loaded)
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24 (not loaded)
 4) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (not loaded)
 5) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16 (not loaded)
Selection [aes]:
```

Default selected cipher is between `[]`.

Comment: I thought the minimum key-size for AES was 128? Why so weak?

Comment: @Razick Based on the other answer to this question, I assume that the 16 refers to the key size in _bytes_, i.e. 16*8 = 128 _bits_.