# Ubuntu 12.04 /home encryption option during installation info?

Tags: 12.04, encryption, drive

Does anyone know of a good link to info about this option?
I've tried to google the info with much luck.
Like what is the name of the package used for encrypting?
Key length?
Algorithm used?
Is it cross distro?
etc.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94298/which-algorithm-does-encrypt-home-directory-use

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installer will set up eCryptFS to handle individual user home mounts.  The packages installed are `libecryptfs0` and `ecryptfs-utils`.  Note that this is NOT the same as a whole-partition or whole-drive encryption, it simply mounts the encrypted data that exists on the unencrypted hard drive (in `/home/.ecryptfs/username`) to the user's home directory.

It would appear based on  what I [found in the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Design) that the cypher is AES with 16-byte (128-bit) keys.  These keys are generated per-file, and are then themselves encrypted with your own encryption key, which is finally encrypted symmetrically using your passphrase.  eCryptfs is cross-distro, and built into the kernel.  There's some good information about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html), especially in [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9400).  I apologize that the links are so old, but they appear to be very relevant today.